# Баг с новогодними шляпами при выполнении сниппета

Tags: дефект, новогодние-шляпы

Недавно обнаружил баг со шляпами.

При выполнении сниппета (например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219944/176217)) шляпа не следует за аватаром, а остается на месте.

Если навестись на шляпу вне аватара, то раскроется мини-профиль, который также будет фиксировано спозиционирован. Тогда при закрытии сниппета шляпа будет уже ниже аватара.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Шляпы такие шляпы...

Comment: Гифку бы покрупнее. А то глаза сломать можно.

Comment: Шапки зависают в "воздухе" при скролле)))

Comment: Прямо скажем, в этом году шляпы какие-то убогие, наверное попорчены коронавирусом

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ограничение в 2 мб не дает

Comment: @Voprositel видимо у вас какие-то прожорливые настройки. Уместился в 500Кб.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, мне стало интересно, как вы увеличили размер моей гифки?

Comment: Нейросеть обучил на улучшение качества, конечно же :) Да просто новую записал, делов-то.